# Flow message not delivered in unit test

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a consumer that reads messages off MutableSharedFlow (which acts as an EventBus in my application). I am trying to write a unit test to show that passing a message into the Flow triggers my Listener.

This is my Flow definition:

```
class MessageBus {

    private val _messages = MutableSharedFlow<Message>()
    val messages = _messages.asSharedFlow()

    suspend fun send(message: Message) {
        _messages.emit(message)
    }
}
```

Here is the Listener:

```
class Listener(private val messageBus: MessageBus) {

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())

    init {
        scope.launch {
            messageBus.messages.collectLatest { message ->
                when (message) {
                    is CustomMessage -> handleCustomMessage(message)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally here is my unit test:

```
class CommandTest {
    @Test
    fun `should process CustomMessage`(): Unit = runBlocking {
        val messageBus = MessageBus()
        val listener = Listener(messageBus)
        messageBus.send(CustomMessage("test command"))
        //argumentCaptor...verify[removed for brevity]
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the above code does not trigger the break point in my Listener (breakpoint on line `init` is triggered, but a message is never received and no breakpoints triggered in the `collectLatest` block).

I even tried adding a `Thread.sleep(5_000)` before the verify statement but the result is the same. Am I missing something obvious with how coroutines work?

Edit: if it matters this is not an Android project. Simply Kotlin + Ktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that since the code is in the **init** block in the **Listener** once you initialize `val listener = Listener(messageBus, this)` in the test it reads all messages and at this point you have none then in the next line you emit a message `messageBus.send(CustomMessage("test command"))` but your `launch` block should have finished by then. You can emit the message first or place your `launch` in an loop or in a different method that can be called after you emit the message

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the loop suggestion? Wouldn't this create a multiple coroutines unnecessarily?

Comment: My intention was not to use launch there because it may keep your main thread open because in this case the emit is not publishing to the flow apparently but I leave u another comment below on how I think it should work. Sorry for the late response I have been out for some days

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recomend reading this [article](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/test#assert) about how to test flows in Android.

Secondly in your example the issues arise from having the scope inside the `Listener` hardcoded. You should pass the scope as a parameter and inject it in the test:

```
class Listener(private val messageBus: MessageBus, private val scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob()))
```

---

```
class CommandTest {
    @Test
    fun `should process CustomMessage`(): Unit = runBlockingTest {
        val messageBus = MessageBus()
        val listener = Listener(messageBus, this)
        messageBus.send(CustomMessage("test command"))
        //argumentCaptor...verify[removed for brevity]
    }
}
```

I would also recomend using `runBlockingTest` instead of `runBlocking` so your tests don't have to actually wait. It will also fail in case any coroutines are left running once the test finishes.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, however, this is not an Android project. Will this change your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but this does not seem to work. Passing `this` as the context still results in the breakpoint never being hit, and the assert test failing. I cannot use `runBlockingTest` as it seems to be only available on Android.

Comment: in that case [this](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/index.html) may be useful. Passing the runBlocking scope might block the the flow from collecting. Should try passing a `TestScope` or a custom one in an `Unconfined ` Dispatcher

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this

```
class Emitter {
  private val emitter: MutableSharedFlow<String> = MutableSharedFlow()

  suspend fun publish(messages: Flow<String>) = messages.onEach {
      emitter.emit(it)
  }.collect()

  fun stream(): Flow<String> = emitter
}
```

the collect at the end of your onEach will be used to trigger the collection initially as a terminal operation... I need further understanding on emit because it does not work as I expect in all cases and when used in this way you have initially it does not post anything in your Flow unless you collect first to process

Then in your collector itself

```
class Collector {

suspend fun collect(emitter: Emitter): Unit = coroutineScope {
    println("Starting collection...")
    emitter.stream().collect { println("collecting message: $it") }
  }
}
```

then your main (or test)

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
  withContext(Dispatchers.Default + Job()) {
    val emitter = Emitter()
    val collector = Collector()

    launch {
        collector.collect(emitter)
    }

    emitter.publish(listOf("article#1", "article#2", "article#3", "article#4").asFlow())
  }
}
```

output:

```
Starting collection...
collecting message: article#1
collecting message: article#2
collecting message: article#3
collecting message: article#4
```

Comment: This sample does not work. You need to cancel the job after publishing.